# Probability that exactly 1 out of N people selects their own name

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am given the following problem:

$N$ names are put into a hat, each person randomly selects a name. What is the probability that exactly one person draws their own name? This is done without replacement.

What I know: The probability that the first person draws their own name is $(1/N)$, then we multiply that by the probability that the second, third, fourth, etc. do not select their names is $\dfrac{N-2}{N-1}\times\dfrac{N-3}{N-2} \times ....$ It ends up being $\dfrac{1}{N(N-1)}$.

This situation is similar if the second person draws their name when the first, third, fourth, etc. do not draw their own name. So it occurs $N$ times $N \times \dfrac{1}{N(N-1)}$. Therefore, $P(X = 1) = \dfrac{1}{N-1}$.

However, if I run this simulation multiple times in R with $N = 30$, I get $P(X = 1)$ to be about $.33 - .37$. And $1/29$ is not close to $.33$. Am I thinking of this wrong? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: With $3$ people : for the second person to draw his name, the first person must have drawn the third person's name, leaving only one possibility.

Comment: If the first person draws their own name, and the second person draws the name of third person, then there are $N-2$ outcomes for third person, not $N-3$. And if the second person draws the name of fourth person, then there are $N-3$ outcomes for third person. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 2):

There $n!$ possibilities in total and in $n\times!(n-1)$ of them exactly one person draws his own hat.

Factor $n$ for the number of persons that can occur to be the one that draws his own hat.

Factor $!(n-1)$ for the number of derangements concerning the other $n-1$ persons.

So the probability is:$$\frac{n\times!(n-1)}{n!}=\frac{!(n-1)}{(n-1)!}$$

Here $!n$ is a notation for the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of a set of size $n$.

Based on the equality $!n=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$ that can be found in the link we can also write this probability as:$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Note that for large $n$ it will be close to $e^{-1}\approx0,3678$.

---

edit:

The probability that the first person draws his own name is indeed $\frac1n$. Under the condition that this happens the probability that the second will not draw his own name is indeed $\frac{n-2}{n-1}$. But to find the probability that the third will not draw his own name under both conditions we must split up in two cases: number $2$ has taken the hat of number $3$ (in that case it is for certain that number $3$ will not draw his own hat) or number $2$ has not taken the hat of number $3$ (in that case number $3$ has chance $\frac{n-3}{n-2}$ of not drawing his hat).

This has not been taken into account in the calculation that you propose and illustrates why things go wrong there.